# Debug lapply / loop script over n dfs

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, lapply

I have 61 dfs with uniform structure. Eventually I would like to bind them all in one large df but before I’d like to:

```
select 4 columns from all df = df[ ,c(3,8,13,17)]
change three of the columns from factor to character using df$[columnName] = as.character(df$columnName)
```

Addition: all the dfs in the global environment have names starting with “9” (number 9). and end with ".csv’

The script that I have prepared is:

```
process_df = function( df_name ) {
  # import the CSV
  df = read.csv( df_name )
  
  # modify the df and return the result
  filtered = df[ ,c(3,8,13,17) ]
  filtered$Name = as.character( filtered$Name)
  filtered$Zipcode = as.character(filtered$Zipcode)
  filtered$Address = as.character(filtered$Address)
}

# loop over each of the file names
files = list.files( pattern = "*.csv" )
results_list = lapply( files, process_df )

# combine the results
result = do.call( "rbind", results_list )
```

but I get an error after running `results_list = lapply(files, process_df)`:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Address", value = character(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 133652

Comment: Why do you have `rbind` in quotation marks? That makes it a character string not a function call.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The error appears before the last line of code. The error comes after `results_list`. But you are right and I will fix that portion! Thank you.

Comment: rbind in quotation marks should be okay in a do.call() function. But your function that creates a data frame should return the filtered dataset at the end: add a new line in the function stating only `filtered` and try again

Comment: And if you still have problems, run `traceback()` on the error and see which line is causing it.

Comment: (It doesn't much matter, but I might suggest replacing your 3 `as.character()` lines with `col_to_char = c("Name", "Zipcode", "Address"); filtered[col_to_char] = lapply(filtered[col_to_char], as.character)`. It's a little more extensible

Comment: @GregorThomas maybe it's even better to just add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the read.csv function so that no factors are created, and only convert the fourth selected variable to a factor if necessary

Comment: @Parfait appreciate the shout-out, but by all indications OP's dataframes are in a `list` here!

Answer (score 1):

**Issue Found**

One of the dfs had one column out of place so the subset didn't grab "uniform" columns causing the error (probably). After fixing that, no errors appeared and I compiled 4 mil addresses! Thank you all for your wonderful suggestions, they made the script much cleaner!

In short, the script works as long as the .csv files in the directory are uniform. I guess a better script would grab the columns based on their names and not their position!

Comment: One other comment - the `process_df` function appear to (a) select a few columns and (b) specify their classes. You could do both of these in a single call to `data.table::fread` or `readr::read_csv`, which would probably speed up your processing time 10x or more. `results_list = lapply( files, data.table::fread, select = c(3,8,13,17), colClasses = rep("character", 4))`. You could also specify the columns to read-in by their names, which would make the function robust even if columns are in different orders or positions in different files/

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Leon Samson, the problem is that the `process_df` function as written returns the contents of the `filtered$Address` column (a character vector), when in fact you should be returning the entire data.frame `filtered`

```r
process_df = function( df_name ) {
  # import the CSV
  df = read.csv( df_name )
  
  # modify the df and return the result
  filtered = df[ ,c(3,8,13,17) ]
  filtered$Name = as.character( filtered$Name)
  filtered$Zipcode = as.character(filtered$Zipcode)
  filtered$Address = as.character(filtered$Address)

  # return data.frame "filtered"
  return(filtered)
}

# loop over each of the file names
files = list.files( pattern = "*.csv" )
results_list = lapply( files, process_df )

# combine the results
result = do.call( "rbind", results_list )
```

For a *much* faster version of your code, try `data.table::rbindlist` to combine your data.frames...

```r
process_df = function( df_name ) {
  # import the CSV
  df = read.csv( df_name )
  
  # modify the df and return the result
  filtered = df[ ,c(3,8,13,17) ]
  filtered$Name = as.character( filtered$Name)
  filtered$Zipcode = as.character(filtered$Zipcode)
  filtered$Address = as.character(filtered$Address)

  # return data.frame "filtered"
  return(filtered)
}

# loop over each of the file names
files = list.files( pattern = "*.csv" )
results_list = lapply( files, process_df )

# combine the results
result = data.table::rbindlist( results_list )
result = as.data.frame( result )
```